# How to save CV_32F type CV::Mat to a file without loosing precision?

Tags: opencv

I'm using cv::PCA class for a face recognition project. I convert photos of faces to one row vectors, concatenate them to one big array and feed to pca, to acquire a new space in which I can try to use distance for recognition. Problem is, that calculating the pca from scratch each time I start the program is really time consuming (almost five minutes). I figured out that I need to save the calculated pca to hard drive, and load it when I start the program again. And here is the problem. As I can see, all cv::Mat objects in cv::PCA are of type CV_32F. When i try to save it as a normal picture, its converted to 8 bit image, and there is some data lost. When i use XML/YAML persistence, the generated file is really big, and data is also lost (I have saved it, loaded to another structure and ran `cerr<<sum(pca_orginal.mean==pca_loaded.mean)[0]<<endl` to check how big is the difference). Right now I'm trying to use `std::ofstream::write` with `std::ofstream::binary` flag, and `istream::read`, but there are some type issues (`out.write(_pca.mean.data,_pca.mean.rows*_pca.mean.cols*4/*CV_32F->4*CV_8U*/\);` generates `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::write(uchar*&, int)`. I've also heard about openexr library and it's file format, but I would rather avoid using additional libraries. I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1 and OpenCV 2.2.

**edit**:
I'm sorry for the confusion. I misread `cv::Mat operator==` description, and thought that it works the opposite way that it does, so `sum(pca_orginal.mean==pca_loaded.mean)[0]` giving 0 is the worse possible result, not the best. It means that XML/YML works fine apart from generating huge files. Also, after using c-style casting I was able to make the binary streams work, but the files generated are also big (over 150MB).

Answer (score 0):

In the C interface, there are functions `cvSave` and `cvLoad` for saving arbitrary matrices.  There are probably C++ interface counterparts, too.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but as I've already wrote, xml functions generate quite big files(because pixel values are written as text) and there seems to be precision loss when using the saved file.

Comment: I see.  Please post the code that you're having problems with.  It should definitely be possible to dump the `data` array to a binary file and read it back without any problems (as long as you're not moving the file between machines that represent floats differently).

Comment: Sorry for the mixup, xml doesn't cut on precision. Right now after using c-style cast to (const char*) i was able to write and read mean matrix, so it looks that it might work for the others. right now I only need to check if all of the data will have reasonable (less thaan 100MB) size after writing to hdd).

Comment: You could always compress with gzip (after saving the file) to reduce redundancy in the data.  The effectiveness of compression will of course depend on the entropy of your data.